# Multiple fill colors in star rating survey

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to build a 5 star rating responses to set of survey questions. The stars need to be filled with gold color if the rating is 1 or 2 else it need to be filled with green color if the rating is more than 2 star.

I have built the 5 stars which gets filled with gold color. How can I make it dynamic to change color to green?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rating {
  font-size: 0;
}

.rating:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating-label {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"] {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:checked~.rating-label {
  font-size: 0;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:checked~.rating-label:before {
  content: "\2605";
  color: #feca02;
}

.rating-label.is-active {
  color: #feca02;
}

.rating-large .rating-label {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.rating-large .rating-label:before {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.rating-small .rating-label {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.rating-small .rating-label:before {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.rating {
  margin: 15px auto;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 55px;
  background-color: #1d1f20;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form class="demoForm">
    <div class="rating rating-large" dir="rtl">
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="5" value="5" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="5">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="4" value="4" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="4">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="3" value="3" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="3">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="2" value="2" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="2">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="1" value="1" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="1">&#9734</label>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `nth-child` selector to change the colour dependant on the number of stars chosen.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rating {
  font-size: 0;
}

.rating:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating-label {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"] {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:checked~.rating-label {
  font-size: 0;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:checked~.rating-label:before {
  content: "\2605";
  color: #feca02;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(1):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #feca02;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(3):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: green;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(5):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: pink;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(7):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: purple;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(9):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: red;
}

.rating-label.is-active {
  color: #feca02;
}

.rating-large .rating-label {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.rating-large .rating-label:before {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.rating-small .rating-label {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.rating-small .rating-label:before {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.rating {
  margin: 15px auto;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 55px;
  background-color: #1d1f20;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form class="demoForm">
    <div class="rating rating-large" dir="rtl">
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="5" value="5" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="5">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="4" value="4" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="4">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="3" value="3" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="3">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="2" value="2" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="2">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="1" value="1" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="1">&#9734</label>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

> The stars need to be filled with gold color if the rating is 1 or 2
>   else it need to be filled with green color if the rating is more than
>   2 star

For this specific case you could use the following...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rating {
  font-size: 0;
}

.rating:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating-label {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"] {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:checked~.rating-label {
  font-size: 0;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:checked~.rating-label:before {
  content: "\2605";
  color: green;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(7):checked~.rating-label:before,
.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(9):checked~.rating-label:before{
  color: #feca02;
}

.rating-label.is-active {
  color: #feca02;
}

.rating-large .rating-label {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.rating-large .rating-label:before {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.rating-small .rating-label {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.rating-small .rating-label:before {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.rating {
  margin: 15px auto;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 55px;
  background-color: #1d1f20;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form class="demoForm">
    <div class="rating rating-large" dir="rtl">
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="5" value="5" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="5">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="4" value="4" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="4">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="3" value="3" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="3">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="2" value="2" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="2">&#9734</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rate" id="1" value="1" />
      <label class="rating-label" for="1">&#9734</label>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Turnip. This worked. However when I duplicate the same with a different input ids for second question its resetting. When I fill say 3 star for Q1 and then click on Q2 response, then Q1 response is getting reset to 0 stars. Can you please help to fix this?

Comment: As I mentioned on your other question, each group of inputs must have a unique name attribute.

Comment: Got that, missed to notice that. Thanks again!!